# How can I redirect all visitors to a subdirectory but still have access to the root directory for development

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm about to start building a site and I've set up an "Under Construction" site at http://positivechange.cl

I'd like to work directly on the root directory during development so that I don't have to move all files from a development subdirectory to the root directory, so I'd like to redirect users to something like http://positivechange.cl/maintenance

After searching online I know how to redirect to the subdirectory using `RedirectMatch ^/$ /subdirectory/` on the .htaccess file, but that doesn't allow me to access the root directory and check how the site is going.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)dev=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ maintenance.html [L,NC]
```

Key is use of query parameter `dev=1`. Without this query parameter site will show `maintenance.html`. But if you add `?dev=1` to your URL then you can access your development website.

Answer (score 0):

Because you already using redirect... 
try comment that line and tell me how it's goes. 
Hope this helpful cheers~

Comment: I want to be able to access the root directory without disabling the redirect.